# \edef containing utf8 umlaut characters

Tags: macros, input-encodings

Is it somehow possible to have utf8 characters (e.g. german umlauts) inside `\edef` ?
The following example document behaves fine if the umlaut is given directly as argument like `\convertTest{Müller}`. The resulting output is "Mueller" after conversion.
If "Müller" is given via a `\edef` like in `\convertTest{\authorname}`, the resulting output is not as expected ("M.ller"), although the message on `\newcommand` entry (before convert) is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{stringstrings}


\newcommand{\convertTest}[1]{  
\message {before convert: #1}  
\convertword[q]{#1}{}{ue}  
\message {after convert: \thestring}  
\thestring \ 
}

\begin{document}  
\convertTest{Müller}  
\edef\authorname{Müller}
\convertTest{\authorname}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Martin is right when he says  : an alternative might be to protect ...

You can to do this with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{stringstrings}


\newcommand{\convertTest}[1]{  
\message {before convert: #1}  
\convertword[q]{#1}{}{ue}  
\message {after convert: \thestring}  
\thestring \ 
}

\begin{document}  
\convertTest{Müller}
\makeatletter  
 \protected@edef\authorname{Müller}
 \makeatother   
 \authorname
\convertTest{\authorname}  
\end{document}
```

You need to use an engine with etex but pfd(e)tex is very common actually

Alternativ :  you can put the definition in your preamble :

```
\makeatletter   
\newcommand{\defauthorname}[1]{ 
 \protected@edef\authorname{#1}
 }
\makeatother
```

and you can use this with

```
\defauthorname{Müller}  
 \authorname
```

Comment: The \makeatletter \protected@edef ... \makeatother  solution works fine and is actually very simple. It solves also other problems, for example it makes possible to use \authorname in a \addcontentsline statement.

Comment: `\protected@edef` seems the (general) way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The umlauts are usually defined as *active characters*, e.g. like `~`. They are basically single-character macros which do not need the backslash in front of them.

Now, `\edef` expands all macros, and therefore also all active characters, until the resulting tokens cannot be expanded any further. This is whats causing the problem: after `\edef` the `ü` isn't a `ü` any longer:

```
\show ü
> ü=macro:
->\UTFviii@two@octets ü.
```

I ran into the same issue when adding group names to my *svn-multi* package, which should be used inside `\csname ... \endcsname`, which also expands like `\edef` (but causes an error if the result is not text-only).

**Solution:**
You could redefine the `ü` locally prior to the `\edef`:
If all what you want to do is to turn the `ü` into `ue` then do this:

```
\def ü{ue}
\edef\authorname{Müller}
\message{\authorname}%   Prints Mueller!
```

An alternative might be to protect the `ü`, e.g. make it robust. I tried
the `\robustify` macro from `etoolbox` but it didn't work. But this might be an issue with my local encodings.

You might also try to use XeTeX, which has native unicode support. But I personally don't have any experience with it.

Comment: `^` and `_` aren't active.

Comment: Thanks, yes there are math super- and subscript characters (catcodes 7 and 8). My bad, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\convertTest[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ü}{ue}}

\begin{document}  
\convertTest{Müller}  
\edef\authorname{Müller}
\convertTest{\authorname}  
\end{document}
```